# UIelement programmatically created. Can I take the name of new created UIelement from variable?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I edited exactly what I want to achieve, this time different example without taken parameter in function.

What I want to achieve is:

```
var array = [String]()
func create() {

var arrayCount = array.count         // will be 0
var nameForUI = "view/(arrayCount)" // will be view0

let nameForUI: UIVIew = {
let view = UIVIew()
return view

}()
array.append(nameForUI)
view.addSubview(nameForUI)
//
}
```

next time if I call create() func , the next view will be called "view1" So my question is, how to achieve this result? every time function will called it will create new element with new name.

Comment: What do you mean by name for the UI element? A `UIButton` for example doesn't have a _name_, but you can reference it

Comment: for example if you call function like that: create (littleButton), you will create UIButton with name littleButton, so if you want to change background then: littleButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor. Is it possible or not? I want to create app that will create row by row with few elements of UIelements. To do that, every name of UIelement must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

To directly answer your question: No, you cannot do that.

Code written in Swift is **compiled** -- it is not an interpreted / scripted language.

So you **cannot** write code that creates a button *named* "littleButton" and then have a line of code `littleButton.backgroundColor = .red`

---

You can *sort of* do this by creating a Dictionary that maintains the "name" of the element as the key, and a reference to the element as the value.

Start with initializing an empty dictionary:

```
var buttonsDict: [String : UIButton] = [String : UIButton]()
```

Your "create" func can start like this:

```
func createButton(named str: String) -> Void {
    // create a button
    let b = UIButton()
    // give it a default title
    b.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
    // add it to our Dictionary
    buttonsDict.updateValue(b, forKey: str)
}
```

When you want to create a button:

```
createButton(named: "littleButton")
```

When you want to access that button *by name*:

```
// use guard to make sure you get a valid button reference
guard let btn = buttonsDict["littleButton"] else { return }
view.addSubview(btn)
```

---

**Edit 2**

Another option, which is perhaps more similar to your edited question:

```
// initialize empty array of views
var viewsArray: [UIView] = [UIView]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // create 5 views
    for _ in 0..<5 {
        create()
    }

    // ...

    // then, somewhere else in your code
    viewsArray[0].backgroundColor = .red
    viewsArray[1].backgroundColor = .green
    viewsArray[2].backgroundColor = .blue
    viewsArray[3].backgroundColor = .yellow
    viewsArray[4].backgroundColor = .orange

}

func create() -> Void {
    // create a view
    let v = UIView()
    // add it to our array
    viewsArray.append(v)
    // add it as a subview
    view.addSubview(v)
}
```

As you see, instead of trying to reference the created views ***by name*** (which you cannot do), you can reference them by array index.

Just remember that arrays are **zero-based**... so the first element added to the array will be at `[0]` not `[1]`.

Comment: I edited my questions and make clarification what I want to achieve

Comment: It's not a problem that we add to view elements with same name? In this case after for in lopp we add 5 x v as a subView.  Don't I get anny error from ViewController? You know I am not so beginner but I can't do it. My app has + button and after every tap i have to create few UI elements in one row , after each row I will add to view 200 points and UIview animation will go down with screen showing new elements. Thiswill be Uiview, Uitextfields and so on. If your example is valid. It will be great.

Comment: @kuba - When creating variables, *they do not have names*. For example: `var view` = UIView()` does ***not*** create a view "named" `view``. It creates a `UIView` object, and while it is in scope the code you are writing can reference it as `view1`. It is a bit difficult to understand if you have not yet learned the basics. But, yes, my `viewsArray` example *is* valid.

Comment: I gave you upVote for your answer, sorry for my my lack of knowledge, I  am programming for a while but I did not know that to be honest

Comment: One more question, if I want to collect two types of UI elements in this way, should I create two different arrays or is any way to do that in one array to stay clean with code

Comment: @kuba - *"... should I create two different arrays ..."* -- there is no way anyone could answer that. What is your app doing? Why do you even need to build an array of views / buttons / labels / whatever? Will you be removing views? Will you be adding subviews? Will you be adding target actions to buttons? Event handlers to text fields? And on and on and on. I suggest that you work on what you're trying to do - if you run into problems, you can ask new, specific questions.

Comment: my app colects data, in one row you have 3 textFIelds putted in 3 UIView, next to these 6 elements (UIView and UITextfields)  is placed button "-" Benath is big + button. + button will call function that will create this 7 UIelements, 6 = 3 textfields in 3 UIViews. 7 element will be - button, if you click - button all elements from one row will be deleted. if you click + button, one row with 7 UI elements will be added. So the point of my function is to create UI elements, and other function will be deleted these elements

Comment: @kuba - Sounds like you want to create a custom view class that contains the *"3 textfields in 3 UIViews. 7 element will be - button""*. Then you only track the add/remove of the custom view (instead of 7 elements). If you will have several "rows" of this custom view, you'll probably be using a scroll view. If you may have more than several, then it sounds like a table view, and instead of having to track adding / removing custom views, you manage them in your data and use custom table view cells. Again, start working on it... post new question(s) if you run into trouble.